# I received vs. I've received your mail

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Could someone explain me what is the difference between "I received your e-mail" and "I've received your e-mail". Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

With the past tense, *"I received your email,"* it implies that you are plainly thinking of an event happened in the past.

With the present perfect tense, *"I've received your email,"* it implies that you are thinking of an event started happening in the past, and yet continues to have some effects up until the present.

One possible difference is that you should **still have that email** when saying *"I've received your email,"* compared to you might or might not still have it with you (you might have deleted it), when saying *"I received your email."*

Answer (score -1):

Use the simple past (I received your email) if there is a time clue (I received your email yesterday(time clue)). Time is important.

Use the present perfect tense if there is no specific time (I have received your email.). Time is not important (action is important).

Comment: Time isn't of that much importance with either forms. With Past Simple it simply denotes action before Now; anywhere in the past. With Present Perfect this speaks of *since Past and up until this very moment* or *at this very moment* as well as *Now* - meaning around the closest point of this very moment.